# Android Studio issue with static method declaration

Tags: java, static

I am currently trying to make a project which will create a database that has 3 elements, ID, NAME, and STATUS.  Then I need to store all of those values into 3 list views which are all on the same activity. Here is my sqlite code:

```
package com.example.mikediloreto.sqliteproject;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;


public class myDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TB_Student = "student";
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String STATUS = "status";

public myDB(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("Create Table " + TB_Student + " (" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " + NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + STATUS + " TEXT" + ");");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}

public Cursor getStudents() {
    String[] cols = new String[] { ID, NAME, STATUS};
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    return db.query(TB_Student, cols, null, null, null, null, NAME);

}

public Cursor getStudent(int studentId) {
    String[] cols = new String[] { ID, NAME, STATUS};
    String sel = ID + "=?";
    String[] selArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(studentId)};
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    return db.query(TB_Student, cols, sel, selArgs, null, null, null);

}

public long numStudents() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteStatement st = db.compileStatement("SELECT COUNT(1) " + "FROM "+ TB_Student + ";");
    return st.simpleQueryForLong();

}

public long addStudent(String name, String status) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NAME, name);
    cv.put(STATUS, status);
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    return db.insert(TB_Student, null, cv);

}

public boolean delStudent(int studentId) {
    String sel = ID + "=?";
    String[] selArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(studentId) };
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    return (db.delete(TB_Student, sel, selArgs) > 0);
}
```

}

and here is my main activity:

```
package com.example.mikediloreto.sqliteproject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;



public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView lv1=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.leftListView);
    ListView lv2=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.centerListView);
    ListView lv3=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.rightListView);



    setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.*, myDB.getStudents(), new String [] { myDB.ID, myDB.NAME, myDB.STATUS }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0));

    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I call myDB.getStudents(), it tells me that I need to make the method declaration static, but if I make it static, then I get an error telling me that it can't to be static for getReadableDatabase() to work.  Not sure where to go from here, also if there is anything else blatantly wrong let me know.

Also the console is telling me there is an error when I use R.layout.*, and the fix is to put it after the getStudents() call.

Edit: Creating an instance variable worked. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You need to create an instance of your class to use instance methods. If that make sense, then great! However, if that sentence leaves you with questions, then you should review [object oriented concepts in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) before you dig yourself into an even bigger hole :)

Comment: are you doing  an instance for that object? like myDB instanceVariable = new myDB? if not, use it then use the instanceVariable as instanceVariable.getStudents(). just remember to make it public or else you can't access it

Comment: oh my bad, didn't see the answer by KeLiuyue :)

Answer (score 1):

> Your problem is that you can't use class names to access non `static` `public` methods within a class .

- So you can use `myDB mMyDB;` and use `Class object` to access the `getStudents` method .
- And you can make your method `static`

And in your `myDB` .You can change to this .

```
public myDB(Context contextr) {
    super(context, NAME , null , DB_VERSION , mull);
}
```

And in your `MainActivity` .

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
myDB mMyDB;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView lv1=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.leftListView);
    ListView lv2=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.centerListView);
    ListView lv3=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.rightListView);


    mMyDB = new myDB(this);
    // edited here , change the layout
    setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.your_layout, mMyDB.getStudents(), new String [] { myDB.ID, myDB.NAME, myDB.STATUS }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0));

}
}
```

**Edit**

You should change `R.layout.your_layout` to the layout you have .

**Note**

And then modify your class name, this writing is not very standardized .

Sample like **MyDB**

The class name of the first letter should be uppercase.

Comment: tried it but it didn't make a difference. still getting the same issues.

Comment: This is not a bad answer, but if you can explain to the OP what it means to **instantiate** an object, it might help.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I'm still getting errors but that is cause by R.layout.* which produces 2 errors, <identifier> expected and illegal start of expression.

Comment: You can use specific layout in `R.layout.your_layout`